# mod_rewrite not setting variables when I rewriterule

Tags: .htaccess, variables, mod-rewrite

I think this is specific to me, but I want to redirect a user to an alternate image when the requested one does not exist.  This part works.  I also want to set an enviromental variable to turn the cache off for this one image, which is what I am having trouble with. My flag `E=`to set an enviromental variable is not working.  I have apache2.2

In my rewrite log,  I am getting this 
`xx.xx.xx.xx - - [20/Jul/2011:09:57:24 --0500] [xx.xx.xx.xx/sid#86cad58][rid#89dde90/initial] (5) setting env variable 'devel' to '1'`

When I try to print this variable using a header function,  it comes out as (null).
ie: `debugger   hello_(null)`

if I set it using SetEnv directive,  it sets the variable, but RewriteRule does not chanage the variable. My conditional header statements never print unless I set the variable using this method.

Here is my .htaccess

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from xx.xx.xx.xx

RewriteEngine on  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^.*\.jpg$ /product.jpg [L,E=devel:1]

header always set cache-control "no-cache" env=devel
header always unset expires env=devel
header always add debugger "hello_%{devel}e"
```

OK, I think I might have bug in my apache build.
`xx.xx.xx.xx - - [20/Jul/2011:14:24:12 --0500] [xx.xx.xx.xx/sid#4b60d58][rid#4e6eeb0/initial] (5) setting env variable 'devel' to '1'`
 does not change the enviromental variable even though it says it does. 
`xx.xx.xx.xx - - [20/Jul/2011:14:24:12 --0500] [xx.xx.xx.xx/sid#4b60d58][rid#4e7f3a0/initial/redir#1] (5) setting env variable 'devel' to '1'`
 does change it.  Notice the **redir#1** in the second log entry.  I get this accomplished with this rule `RewriteRule ^.*product.jpg$ - [L,E=devel:1]` but it seems to run it on every request,  so I am concerned about a performance hit.

Comment: Could this be because I am making a seperate request after the first rewrite, so the file now exists, and my variable is reset in the new request and doesn't get reset because of my rewritecond?